# Replacing using wildcards or regex in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have values like this in my column: **/1/0/101.00_1234.jpg**

Now I want to replace the /1/0 with something else. Problem is, it can differ from row to row. It can be /h/a as well. How could I do that without any additional tools?

Thanks

Comment: Would removing the first 4 characters solve the problem? Or can you have values like `/ab/cd` that need removing?

Comment: @Derek Tomes: I bet it is just a common implementation of separating files by different directories, so there are constant 4 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` key word:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

for example:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(myfield, '/', -3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you just need to replace first 4 chars, so use `SUBSTRING` and `CONCAT` functions:

```
CONCAT('/a/b', SUBSTRING(colunm_name, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a stored function which searches for the rightmost "/" in the field content and deletes all characters before that position. Then use this stored function to update the field.
Of is this already an "additional tool" -? In this case use an inline function like (not tested)

```
RIGHT(fieldname,LENGTH(fieldname) - LOCATE('/', reverse(fieldname))
```